# How do I get the name of a Job in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, job-scheduling

I've tried `$this->getName()`  inside the laravel Job

This is my sample job class

```
class PrepareCustomersSearchExportJob extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
    {
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    private $path;
    private $filename;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($path, $filename)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
             echo  “Name  = “. $this->getName();    
    }
}
```

But the method above tells me `getName()` isn't defined.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of the class(in your case the Job Class) in php, you can use the get_class() method like so

```
echo  “Name  = “. get_class($this);
```